# Eclipse RCP - hiding the editor

Tags: editor, eclipse-rcp

I followed the [Vogella RCP Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#iapplication) and created an Application, lloking like that:

[image]

The "My View" was added explicitely to the perspective. 
The Editor below was there on default.

**Questions:**

- How can I disable the default Editor?
- Where are the Workbench and the Perspective on the image above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your perspective

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        this.layout = layout;

        String editorAreaId = layout.getEditorArea();
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
}
```

this should disable your editor